# What does 幾分 means in 我愛你有幾分?

Tags: songs, mistakes

The lyric of a popular song "月亮代表我的心" ([YouTube video](https://youtu.be/hj4bnnek9MU)) contains the phrase "我愛你有幾分".

This is my interpretation:

1. 我 means I, me
2. 愛 means love, care
3. 你 means you
4. 有 means to have or to have something you shouldn't have
5. 幾 means few
6. 分 means separation, divide

So I think it should be translated to "I love something you have with few division."

Can't figure where I am wrong.

Comment: 十分 is 100%; 五分 50%; 三分 30%．You get the idea.

Comment: Quote:- "I love something you have with few division" LOL. I really like this; like another song titled "Love you to pieces" Come on, we all know you know the correct contextual translation of 我愛你有幾分; good imaginative try though :)

Comment: Oh, I forgot, "Love you to pieces" would be 爱你成碎片  Can't figure where I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 我 = I

> 愛你 = love you

> 有幾分? (in what degree) = how deep? --> how much?

> 我愛你有幾分? = how deep I love you

分(degree) here is a classifier for depth

Example:

沒**半分**愛意 (don't have **a tiny bit** of love) 半分 --> very little/ very lightly

有幾分愛意 (have some degree of love) 幾分 --> mildly

**十分**愛你 (love you **very much**); 十分 --> fully

Comment: Please can you check my answer 3rd or 4th here edited the answer

Comment: As my comment stated, 幾 in a questioning phrase doesn't mean  'few/ some'. It is a prefix  for 'how much' ,  'how many',

Comment: Understood. Earlier I couldn't see the wording neither it as a question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand 分 here.

分 does not mean "division" here. Here 分 means the "points" (test score), in an exam or a contest where the perfect score is ten.

分 can also means "perdec" (*per ten*, a tenth), as a synonym of 成.

> 三分  three points (out of ten), three perdec (3/10)
>
> 五分  five points (out of ten), five perdec (5/10)
>
> 十分 ①[original meaning] ten points (out of ten), perfect score, full marks ②[extended meaning] "perfectly", very, extremely
>
> 幾分  how many points (out of ten), how many perdec

Assuming that there is an exam called "love", how many points can I get from the exam?

> 我愛你有幾分？
>
> How many points (out of ten) do I love you?
>
> How many perdec do I love you?
>
> = How much do I love you?

Extra examples:

> 三分天注定，七分靠打拼。 [famous lyrics]
>
> Three points depend on fate, while seven points depend on hardworking.
>
> 3/10 depends on fate, 7/10 depends on hardworking.
>
> [Chinese version of "nature versus nurture"]

> 逢人只說**三分**話，未可全拋一片心。[ancient proverb]
>
> Every time you meet a person, you should only tell them **three perdec (3/10)** of your mind. You should not "throw the entire heart to them" (tell them all your mind).

---

**Some knowledge about the Chinese culture of proportions**

Western culture prefers to use "percent" (*per hundred*, a hundredth), while Chinese culture traditionally uses "perdec" (*per ten*, a tenth), known as 分, 成, 折.

Examples:

> 三分  = three perdec (three tenths, 3/10)
>
> 七分 = seven perdec (seven tenths, 7/10)
>
> 八成  = eight perdec (eight tenths, 8/10)
>
> 九成 = nine perdec (nine tenths, 9/10)

折 is only used for discounts.

> 九折 = nine perdec remaining (i.e. 10% discount)
>
> 八折 = eight perdec remaining (i.e. 20% discount)
>
> 八五折 (8.5折) = 8.5 perdec remaining (i.e. 15% discount)

---

**Disputes**

As 分 is also a traditional Chinese unit of length, which is currently defined as ⅓ centimetre (in mainland China) or 10/33 centimetre (in Taiwan), some people believe that it is better to parse it as the depth of love measured in this length unit, instead of points or perdecs.

Examples:

> 入木三分  [idiom]
>
> [literally] into the wood for three *fen* of depth
>
> [figuratively] written in a forceful hand, penetrating, profound

---

Wait, this dispute might really be the different usage of 分 between mainland China and Taiwan, because the dictionaries really shows different definitions:

[image: 现代汉语词典]

*Xiandai Hanyu Cidian* dictionary from mainland China:

> ⑧ 十分之一（用于某些计量单位或抽象事物）：分米 | 分升 | 九分成绩，一分缺点
>
> ⑧ a tenth (for some units or something abstract): 分米 (decimetre) | 分升 (decilitre) | 九分成绩，一分缺点 (nine tenths of achievement, and one tenth of shortcoming)

[image: 教育部重編國語辭典修訂本]

*Ministry of Education Mandarin Chinese Dictionary* from Taiwan:

> (6) 計算程度深淺的單位。如「一分努力，一分收穫。」「逢人只說三分話。」
>
> (6) A unit to measure depth, e.g. 一分努力，一分收穫 (one *fen* of hardworking produces one *fen* of rewards) and 逢人只說三分話 (every time you meet a person, you should only say three *fen* of words)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118598/discussion-on-answer-by-victor-what--means-in).

Comment: 這裡的「幾分」，不是分數或百分比，這裡的表現偏重情感的表現，所以Tang Ho才是對的唷！

Comment: @TangHo 可能真是陸臺差異，我在最後發了《现代汉语词典》（中國大陸）與《教育部重編國語辭典修訂本》（臺灣）這兩本詞典，真的給出了不同的解釋。前者有十分之一的義項，但是沒有深淺程度的義項。後者有深淺程度的義項，但是沒有十分之一的義項。

Comment: 很好，「月亮代表我的心」是臺灣歌，登麗君是臺灣人。臺灣作曲者及聴眾絕不會把「有幾分」理解成「有幾多分數」或「有幾分成數」

Answer (score 0):

几分 can mean either 几成/十分之几(n/10) or 一些(a bit) according to context.

> 几成；十分之几(n/10)

E.g. 有几分把握? 我有十分把握/我有十成把握.

In your context, 几分 means *a few*, *a little*, *some* or *somewhat/somehow*.

So, 我爱你有几分: *I somehow love you.* Or *I love you a bit.*

Comment: Yes. Almost every word, in all languages of the World, has more than one meaning or definition. As always the situational context would determine which meaning / definition to use, (unless poetic license is liberally applied)  Hence the problem the OP has, which is he took one possible definition, "separation / division", doggedly stuck to that and thus went down the wrong rabbit hole.

Comment: I went the rabbit hole due to pauses or wording. The problem was in sequence 你有 meant you have.

Comment: @Haizme 我爱你有几分 can be worded as 我对你的爱有几分.  This probably helps you a bit.

Comment: Quote:- "The problem was in sequence 你有 meant you have" Well, you got the sequence incorrectly. The sentence 我爱你有几分? should be sequenced as (我爱你) -- (有几分) and not (我爱) -- (你有) -- (几分) Thus (我爱你) -- (有几分) would be (I love you) -- (to what degree or by how much)? The incorrect sequence of (我爱) -- (你有) -- (几分) would end up as (I love) -- (you have) -- (what degree / how much) which is where the problem lies.

Comment: Opppsss. I commented before seeing your answer below. So you got the sequence now? BTW, "I have some depth in loving you" is not exactly right because 我爱你有几分 is a question, not a comment. So, it should read, "I love you to what degree or by how much or how deep?"

Comment: Thanks it's new to me that questions are asked like this in chinese. if you can tell me more abt asking  questions I would be grateful.

Comment: You must read the stanza as a whole, i.e. 你问我爱你有多深, 我爱你有几分.It started off with 你问, "you asked....", (meaning you "questioned me as to how deep is my love for you"), and the following-on verse 我爱你有几分 is just a second half of this question. Of course, it could be 你问我爱你有多深, 你问我爱你有几分. So, it is more a "reverse question", i.e. the singer is repeating a question asked of him. So it's a question in that sense. Much like "You asked how much I need you, must I explain; I need you, oh my darling, like roses need rain" from the song "The Twelfth of Never"  https://youtu.be/wyQBWRaS3Mo

Comment: This song being in English, you should have no problem getting the sequencing right. But a person very new to English might sing it as (You asked how much) -- (I need you must) -- (I explain); (I need you oh my) -- (darling like roses need rain)  :)

Comment: @WayneCheah 我爱你有几分 could be either a question or a comment. In the song, it's a comment.

Comment: @dan  我的情也真, 我的爱也真, 月亮代表我的心 is the answer to the question?  The singer is repeating a question asked of him.

Comment: Thanks a lot 谢谢。

Comment: I suppose what @dan meant was it is a "comment" on a question asked of the singer. In this sense he is correct. In this sense, 我的情也真, 我的爱也真, 月亮代表我的心 would not be an answer but a comment on a question being commented upon? I think we have exhausted all the possibilities and should now move on? Good luck on your learning journey.

Comment: @WayneCheah 你问我爱你有多深 is a question and 我爱你有几分 is a self answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the song the pauses/wording were there like this
我愛，你有，幾分。
I love,you have, some seperation.

Now after seeing the answers I think it was meant like this.
我愛你，有幾分。I love you, having some depth.

I have some depth in loving you.

Comment: Is this okay...

Comment: No, in this context 幾 doesn't mean 'few'. It is a prefix that indicates 'how much' 'how many' ; 分 doesn't mean separation. It is a classifier for depth.  'Both 我愛你有多深?' and '我愛你有幾分?' mean 'how deep I love you?'